# Endpoint responds with error 403 only when running Playwright test but not when reproduce steps manually

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

How to proceed when Playwright tests fail at call to action buttons (like register, add to cart) in a production website but they are working if the same steps are done manually.

For example a test always fail when trying to register a new user, but registration works ok when I perform the same actions manually in the same website.

Steps performed in the test: go to website, click on user icon, type in the user email to be created in the registration modal, click on Continue.

**Website UI:** "An error ocurred, please try again".

**Console tab:** "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 /api/account/profile/auth-options:1".

**Network tab:**  endpoint auth-options request header status code 403 Forbidden. Access Denied  You don't have permission to access  on this server.

The test fails due to timeout after the login function call:

```js
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { LandingPage } from '../pageObjects/landingPage';
import { LoginModalPage } from '../pageObjects/loginModalPage';

test.describe('test suite', () => {
  test.beforeEach(async({ page }) => {
    const landingPage = new LandingPage(page);
    await landingPage.goToLandingPage();
  }); 

  test('add product to the cart', async ({ page }) => {
    const landingPage = new LandingPage(page);
    const loginModal = new LoginModalPage(page);

    await landingPage.customerInfoButton.click();
    await loginModal.login('test@test.com', 'password');
 
    await landingPage.logout(); 
  });
});
```

Involved page objects:

```js
import { Page, Locator } from '@playwright/test'

export class LoginModalPage {
    readonly page: Page;
    readonly loginModal: Locator;
    readonly emailInputField: Locator;
    readonly contactDataCheckbox: Locator;
    readonly termsAndConditionsCheckbox: Locator;
    readonly continueButton: Locator;

    constructor(page: Page){
        this.page = page;
        this.loginModal = page.getByTestId('landing-screen');
        this.emailInputField = this.loginModal.getByRole('textbox', {name: 'email address'});
        this.contactDataCheckbox = this.loginModal.locator('.gl-checkbox__label', {hasText: 'contact data'});
        this.termsAndConditionsCheckbox = this.loginModal.locator('.gl-checkbox__label', {hasText: 'Register'});
        this.continueButton = this.loginModal.getByRole('button', {name: 'Continue'});
    }

    async login(user: string, password: string){
        await this.emailInputField.pressSequentially(user, {delay: 50});
        await this.contactDataCheckbox.click();
        await this.termsAndConditionsCheckbox.click();
        await this.continueButton.click();
    }
}



import { Page, expect, Locator } from '@playwright/test'

export class LandingPage {
    readonly page: Page;
    readonly cookiesButton: Locator;
    readonly heading: Locator;
    readonly customerInfoButton: Locator;
    readonly accountTab: Locator;

    constructor(page: Page){
        this.page = page;
        this.cookiesButton = page.getByRole('button', { name: 'accept cookies'});
        this.heading = page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'buy now' });
        this.customerInfoButton = page.getByTestId('customer-info-button');
        this.accountTab = page.getByTestId('home-account-tab');
    }

    async goToLandingPage(){
        await this.page.goto('/'); 
    }
    
    async checkTitleAndHeaderPage(){
        await expect(this.page).toHaveTitle(/official site/);
        await expect(this.heading).toBeVisible(); 
    }
}
```

Playwright config:

```js
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  fullyParallel: false,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 2,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  reporter: 'html',
  use: {
    baseURL: websiteURL,
    testIdAttribute: 'data-auto-id', 
    trace: 'on', 
  },

  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { 
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] 
      },
    },
     {
       name: 'Google Chrome',
       use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'], channel: 'chrome' },
     },
  ],

});
```

What I've tried:

- different test input data
- running in different browsers
- adding hard waits
- clear cookies (but I was not able to have it working)

  - set user agent in the code
- checked differences in the endpoint call for the test and manually doing the same in the website in the Network tab:

  - **Referrer Policy**: "no-referrer" in the test, "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" in manual.
  - **content-type response header**: "text/html" in the test, "application/json; charset=utf-8" in manual.
  - **Referer**: *(empty)* in the test, url/endpoint in manual.
  - **Sec-Ch-Ua**: "Chromium";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8" in the test, "Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122" in manual.
  - **Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform**: "Windows" in the test, "Android" in manual.
  - **User-Agent**: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0..." in the test, "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux, Android 6.0..."

Comment: Please share the site or a representative reproduction of it.

Comment: @ggorlen sadly I can't share the site URL because it is a live website. What else can I share?

Comment: Does this page use recaptcha?

Comment: Not enough details. We can just guess based on what is provided.

Comment: @szogoon it does not use recaptcha. Well, a guess and how to implement it might be huge help as well. I provided the tool configuration, test code and what I've tried, I already asked: what else can I specifically share?

Comment: @nZa can you make a reproduction of the relevant site behavior? We need something to run and look at to be able to answer this.